# use UI Icon-sprites without buttons?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Is there a standard way of using the jquery-ui icon sprite without attaching them to buttons?

They are simple to use as they are. For example, attach the class 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-e' to any link that expands and 'ui-icon-circle-arrow-s' in its expanded state. But these feel like hacks, I am new to the jquery(-ui) library and I am just trying to establish some best practices. I have done a few searches here and on google with no real definite answer.

Comment: Including some code might make your question clearer and help explain why you feel your current methods are 'hacks'.

Comment: because instead of reading documentation I lifted them from the css.

Comment: Reread my last comment as "Including some code might A) make your question clearer and B) show if your code is actually a hack."  As already indicated in the answers, jQuery is intentionally very open to support alternate solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes all the icons are added via classes as mentioned in the documentation here: [ui-theming](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API#Icons)

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span>
```

jQuery UI will also adjust the icon based on the state of the container - mainly used for error/default states.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CPLMu/) adjusting the icon to show inline in text -- it is intentionally flexible to be used however and wherever you want.

Comment: Theming url has been moved to [http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/](http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/)

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much nailed it. All of the icons are classed out in css for your pleasure.